# Full Control User Cannot View Items in a List

Tags: list, permissions, site-collection, item, inheritance

User wants to view uniquely secure items on 2 lists (List A/List B)

I went ahead and inherited permissions the lists from the top level site.

Lists A and B say Manage Exceptions because all the items in the list are uniquely secure items.

After all permissions were inherited I gave both user "full control". I hopped on to their account, and navigated the site and found out that when I click View All Site Content, I see both lists and the item count next to each list (indicating that there are items in List A/List B). When I click either list however, there are no items being displayed.

Seems to me it has a lot to do with the uniquely secure items.

Why is the user unable to view the items? Even when it has full control? The only way this user is able to view the items so far is if it is "Site Collection Administrator"

Answer (score 1):

When you start to inherit permissions on the list from the site, you don't effect the items that already have unique permissions. It only effect new items. They could be set up in a way that only the author are able to read the item. If so, the user having control over the item needs to either 1) start inherit permission or 2) give administrative users access to the item.

If that can't be accomplished you need to set permissions on the item(s) using PowerShell.